# Kubernetes - node capacity

Tags: kubernetes

I'm running a small node in gcloud with 2 pods running. Google cloud console shows all resources utilization

<40% cpu utilization

about 8k n\w bytes

about 64 disk bytes.

When adding the next pod, it fails with below error.

**FailedScheduling:Failed for reason PodExceedsFreeCPU and possibly others**

Based on the numbers I see in google console, ~60% CPU is available. is there anyway to get more logs? Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 10):

As kubernetes reserve some space if more cpu or memory is needed you should check the capacity allocated by the cluster instead of the utilization.

`kubectl describe nodes`

You can find a deeper description about the capacity of the nodes in: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/

Comment: To elaborate on this, Kubernetes schedules based on resource requests, not actual utilization. The number reported by the google cloud console is the resource usage.

Comment: agreed. The same cluster, same node that let me run a new pod this morning..not sure what was going on last night that threw this error..

Comment: The output of `kubectl describe nodes` should give you the reported node capacity as well as all the "requested" resources of all the pods running on the node. You can also see the resource requests of your new pod in `kubectl get pod <pod_name>  -o yaml` and see if it fits in the node.

Answer (score 0):

In your helm chart or Kubernetes yaml, check the `resources` section. Even if you have free capacity, if your request would put the cluster over, even if your pod etc wouldn't actually *use* that much, it will fail to schedule. The request is asking for a reservation of capacity. IE:

```
spec:
  serviceAccountName: xxx
  containers:
  - name: xxx
    image: xxx
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "256Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
      limits:
        memory: "256Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
```

If the value for `cpu` there could make the cluster oversubscribed, it won't schedule the pod. So make sure your request reflect actual typical usage. If your requests do reflect actual typical usage, then you need more capacity.